# Calculate recurring end date with dday

Tags: c#, icalendar, dday

I want to get the end date of a recurrence event with DDAY.Ical library. It is possible?

For example i have this code:

```
            calendar = new iCalendar();
            event = new Event();
            rp = new RecurrencePattern("RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10");
            event.RecurrenceRules.Add(rp);
            rp.Parameters.
            event.DTStart = new iCalDateTime(DTToday);
            calendar.Events.Add(event);
            event.GetOccurrences(new iCalDateTime(DTTomorrow));
```

I want to have event.DTEnd and the occurrence with this line

```
  event.GetOccurrences(new iCalDateTime(DTTomorrow));
```

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?